# avoiding memoryError when dealing with large datasets in python

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory

I want to take a benchmark of the time it takes to sort large amounts of data using MergeSort, and I have the following script which opens several text files, reads them, and turns every line (which is a random integer between 1 and 999) into an integer element within a list.

```
data = []
for file in ["10.txt", "100.txt", "1000.txt", "10000.txt", "100000.txt", "1000000.txt", "10000000.txt", "100000000.txt"]:
    tempList = []
    with open(file) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            tempList.append(int(line.rstrip()))
    data.append(tempList)
```

However, the issue is I get a memory error when trying to add 100,000,000 elements to a list. FileIO aside, I tried something alone the lines of this:

```
data = []
for limit in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 10000000]:
    tempList = []
    for i in range(limit):
        tempList.append(random.randint(1,999))
    data.append(tempList)
```

However, the same issue occurs; it simply can't handle 100 million items. Is this an issue with my machine (mine is fairly high end). Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need 100 million items in order to benchmark the time it takes for merge sort to complete?

Comment: Someone just asked the same exact question... hw? Anyway, here's what I commented there:  On a 64 bit system, just the underlying array of pointers will be 800mb. Now, the `int` objects themselves will be about 28 bytes. However, Python caches small ints, so actually, (256/999) of them will be cached. Assuming a uniform distribution,I'd guesstimate (28*(1-256/999) + 8)*100000000*1e-9 gigabytes, or 2.88 gigabytes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Swing the hammer!

Comment: Standard question though: what are you system specs? What operating system, and waht version of Python (64bit, 32bit?)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not exaxtly the same question, actually. The last person was using `readlines` on the file. This one is iterating over it efficiently...

Comment: And, testing it on my system, 64bit python 3.6, I got `2942178888` bytes, so close to my guesstimate!

Comment: Seems like the issue was that I was using 32-bit Python, your calculations are correct, I didn't think it was a system capacity issue as much as some error within IDLE or the Python interpreter or something along those lines.

Comment: @Muffinman yes, 32-bit Python has a hard limit of about 4 gigs of address space (i.e. maximum amount of RAM that can be used by a 32-bit process), but most operating systems limit it further to 3-2 gigs anyway. I know windows will limit it to 2. Get 64bit Python. This isn't 1988, and you aren't on some embedded system, AFAIKT, so there's no good reason to not use 64bit.